# Test fails because of date time formatting when searching for model in database

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Since Laravel 5.6, [Eloquent Date Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) is available.
So I've got a model *MyModel* with:

```
class MyModel extends Model {
    protected $casts = ['from' => 'date:Y-m-d', 'to' => 'date:Y-m-d'];
    protected $dates = ['from', 'to'];
}
```

And the factory:

```
$factory->define(MyModel::class, function(Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'from' => Carbon::instance($faker->dateTime),
        'to' => Carbon::instance($faker->dateTime),
        // some more attributes
    ];
}
```

In my unit test I'm looking for an instance of *MyModel*:

```
/** @test */
public function example() {
    $myModel = factory(MyModel::class)->create();

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('my_models', $myModel->attributesToArray());
}
```

And that's what I get (excerpt):

> Failed asserting that a row in the table [my_models] matches the attributes {
>   "from": "2019-01-12",
>   "to": "2019-02-13",
>   }.
>   Found: [{
>       "from": "2019-01-12 00:00:00",
>       "to": "2019-02-13 00:00:00",
>   }].

Obviously the test fails, because the time is appended at the database record's fields. They are of type `date`.

I could update the assertion to something like this...

```
$this->assertDatabaseHas('my_models', [
    'from' => $myModel->from->toDateTimeString(),
    'to' => $myModel->to->toDateTimeString(),
] + $myModel->attributesToArray());
```

...but that's far away from elegant.

What do I do to make this assertion succeed?

Comment: Can you add the complete code of the test?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan I've added some code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing a new assertion method which formats date properties of the model to `Y-m-d H:i:s` for a correct comparison:

```
protected function assertDatabaseHasModel(string $table, Model $model, ?string $connection = null): void
{
    $attributes = $model->attributesToArray();
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($model);
    $property = $reflection->getProperty('casts');
    $property->setAccessible(true);

    collect($property->getValue($model))->each(function (string $cast, string $field) use ($model, &$attributes) {
        if (Str::startsWith($cast, 'date:')) {
            $attributes[$field] = $model->$field->toDateTimeString();
        } elseif (in_array($cast, ['array', 'object'], true) && $model->$field !== null) {
            $attributes[$field] = $this->castAsJson($model->$field);
        }
    });

    $this->assertDatabaseHas($table, $attributes, $connection);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same problem in my case

below code change worked fine .

```
 $this->assertDatabaseHas('my_models', $myModel->attributesToArray());
 
 change above line to
 
 $this->assertDatabaseHas('my_models', $myModel->getAttributes());
```

It may work for you.
instead of toArray() , attributesToArray() use getAttributes()

Comment: This worked for version 8